# Florist install Ada

Tags: installation, ada

Tried to install Florist on this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZCLBKn9-7o)  but the installation process after ./Configure --prefix=/usr/gnat
I have not gone

```
checking how to run the C preprocessor ... /lib/cpp
checking for aio.h. .. no
checking for dirent.h ... no
checking for errno.h ... no
checking for fcntl.h ... no
checking for grp.h. .. no
checking for locale.h ... no
checking for mqueue.h ... no
...
Socket interface Looks like BSD 4.3
checking for getaddrinfo ... no
configure: WARNING: No getaddrinfo provided by the OS. Will use our own version.
checking for pthread_self in-lpthread ... yes
checking for aio_read in-laio ... no
checking for clock_gettime in-lposix4 ... no
checking for clock_gettime in-lrt ... yes
checking for gethostbyname in-lnsl ... yes
checking for t_bind in-lnsl ... no
checking for t_bind in-lnsl_s ... no
checking for accept in-lsocket ... no
checking for h_errno in-lresolv ... no
using LIBS =-lnsl-lrt-lpthread
checking for egrep ... grep-E
```

In general, all 'no'
what's the catch?
GNAT and florist ( 2013 )
if you continue, then take off the following errors

```
ebanat@ebanat:~/Program/florist$ make -j 4
gcc -c -O2 posix-macros.c
gcc -c -O2 posix-macros-sockets.c
gcc -O2 -DVERSION="\"Florist-2013 (20130319)\"" -DLIBS="\"-lnsl -lrt -lpthread \"" -o c-posix c-posix.c -lnsl -lrt -lpthread 
gnatprep posix-implementation.gpb posix-implementation.adb gnatprep.config -c -r
In file included from pconfig.h:10:0,
                 from posix-macros-sockets.c:13:
addrinfo.h:18:3: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
addrinfo.h:43:42: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
addrinfo.h:43:58: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
addrinfo.h:44:46: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
In file included from pconfig.h:10:0,
                 from c-posix.c:56:
addrinfo.h:18:3: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
In file included from pconfig.h:10:0,
                 from posix-macros.c:45:
addrinfo.h:18:3: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
addrinfo.h:43:42: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
addrinfo.h:43:58: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
addrinfo.h:44:46: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
addrinfo.h:43:42: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
addrinfo.h:43:58: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
addrinfo.h:44:46: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
In file included from /usr/include/errno.h:29:0,
                 from c-posix.c:57:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:26:0,
                 from posix-macros.c:46:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [posix-macros-sockets.o] Ошибка 1
make: *** Ожидание завершения заданий...
make: *** [c-posix] Ошибка 1
make: *** [posix-macros.o] Ошибка 1
```

Comment: "fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file" ... C compiler not installed properly for this job. Find and add to the question: gcc --version, gnatmake --version, and the operating system version you have, e.g. uname -a. Debian (and derivatives) multilibs may be the cause : include files in the wrong place. Or mixing compiler versions. There may be environment variables to fix these if we know what we're fixing.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) 
gcc (GCC) 4.7.4 20130416 for GNAT GPL 2013 (20130314)  
GNATMAKE GPL 2013 (20130314)

All like It is established

Comment: Under Debian there is no need to compile Florist - it is in the main. For Ubuntu you may try installing (or compiling) Debian version of it.

Comment: For Ubuntu and Debian version of one

Comment: @darkestkhan, eBanat is using GNAT GPL 2013, not Debian gnat, so looking in the main [repo?] won't help.

Comment: @darkestkhan - If you want to use the GNAT.Sockets packages, you have to compile FLORIST yourself, as AdaCore has removed those from their distribution of FLORIST (which Ubuntu also seems to use).